# jQuery Autocomplete and gridview footer textbox ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

```
<script src="JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="JQuery/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=(GVOperatos.Footer.FindControl('txtEPFNo')).ClientID%>").
     autocomplete('Search_EPFNo.ashx');});
</script>
```

I cant get gridview footer textbox client id in javascript.how to get that one.
thanx.'

Comment: you'll need to show what `GVOperator.Footer` is - is is a user control on the page? Also you should tag this with ASP.NET. And if your using .NET 4, you can assign a static client id so you don't need all that ridiculous inline code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom selector to select asp.net controls.  Here is a blog post explaining the method.  It comes in handy when needing to select asp.net controls.

http://lanitdev.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/extending-jquery-to-select-asp-controls/